# Sql return multiple rows for records with multiple flags set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Dear smart developers out there,

given following data set:

```
Name    Football  Tennis  Snowboarding
--------------------------------------
Jane    true      false   false
Jack    true      true    false
Sue     false     true    true
```

I would like to obtain the following output from a SQL query:

```
Name    Sport
-------------
Jane    Football
Jack    Football
Jack    Tennis
Sue     Tennis
Sue     Snowboarding
```

Any idea how this can be done?
(I need this to ease the creation of a SQL Report)

Thanks in advance,
AllWorkNoPlay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in various ways.  Here is a method with `cross apply`:

```
select v.name, v.sport
from table t cross apply
     (values (t.name, 'football', t.football), 
             (t.name, 'tennis', t.tennis), 
             (t.name, 'Snowboarding', t.Snowboarding)
     ) v(name, sport, flg)
where flg = 'true';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using UNIONs:

```
select Name, 'Football' as Sport
from tab
where Football = 'true'
UNION ALL
select Name, 'Tennis' as Sport
from tab
where Tennis = 'true'
UNION ALL
select Name, 'Snowboarding' as Sport
from tab
where Snowboarding = 'true'
```

Of course in a normalized data model this would be much easier :)